# Interpolation of a number using csvsimple Filters

Tags: csvsimple

I hav a .csv file where I am manipulating the value by reading the maximum value of Y variable and trying to find an extra polated X value for the manipulated Ymax.

Here is the code.

```
    \csvreader[head to column names, filter test = \ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{3},]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\YRe}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\YRe}}\pgfmathparse{(\val/sqrt(2))}\xdef\d{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\d+20}\xdef\du{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\d-20}\xdef\dl{\pgfmathresult}
% Read the freq that matches -3db Mag value 
    \csvreader[head to column names, filter test = \if{\YRe>\dl and \YRe<\du}\fi,]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\Freq}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\Freq}}\pgfmathparse{\val}\xdef\fd{\pgfmathresult}
```

and the corresponding content in .csv file is

```
Freq    YRe
10  115.8357654
15.13561248 115.8357654
22.90867653 115.8357654
34.67368505 115.8357653
52.48074602 115.835765
79.43282347 115.8357644
120.2264435 115.8357631
181.9700859 115.8357601
275.4228703 115.8357531
416.8693835 115.8357372
630.9573445 115.8357006
954.992586  115.8356169
1445.439771 115.8354252
2187.761624 115.834986
3311.311215 115.8339798
5011.872336 115.8316749
7585.77575  115.8263949
11481.53621 115.814301
17378.00829 115.7866049
26302.67992 115.7232068
39810.71706 115.5782316
60255.95861 115.2474777
91201.08394 114.4968532
138038.4265 112.8135848
208929.6131 109.1379117
316227.766  101.5575321
478630.0923 87.61611542
724435.9601 66.65387878
1096478.196 43.05409574
1659586.907 23.76990366
2511886.432 11.72902177
3801893.963 5.425717497
```

So the first csvreader cmd gives me \d = 115.83/1.414 = 81.91 and I want to use this 81.91 value to calculate the X value within 81.91+- . But I end resulting in different answer, which is not right.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: Could you please add the data as text, rather than as image?

Answer (score 0):

```
    \csvreader[head to column names, filter test = \ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{3},]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\YRe}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\YRe}}\pgfmathparse{(\val/sqrt(2))}\edef\d{\pgfmathresult}
% Initially step coursely to find the row   
    \xdef\ix{25}
    \pgfmathparse{\ix+1}\xdef\iy{\pgfmathresult}
% Roughly choose the \thecsvinputline from 25 and read the \YRe value to begin the search
\csvreader[head to column names, filter test = \ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{\ix},]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\YRe}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\YRe}}\pgfmathparse{\val}\edef\da{\pgfmathresult}
% Convert the floating point number to dimensions to make comparision
\newdimen\dadim
\xdef\dadim{\da pt}

\newdimen\ddim
\xdef\ddim{\d pt}
    
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially \ix)] in {\iy,...,50}
    {\ifdim\dadim>\ddim{
        \csvreader[head to column names, filter test = \ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{\X},]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\YRe}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\YRe}}\pgfmathparse{\val}\xdef\da{\pgfmathresult}
        \xdef\dadim{\da pt}
        \csvreader[head to column names, filter test = \ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{\LastX},]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\YRe}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\YRe}}\pgfmathparse{\val}\xdef\db{\pgfmathresult}
    }\else
    {}
    \fi
}

% Read the freq that matches -3db Mag value     
\csvreader[head to column names, filter equal = {\YRe}{\da},]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\Freq}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\Freq}}\pgfmathparse{\val}\xdef\fa{\pgfmathresult}
\csvreader[head to column names, filter equal = {\YRe}{\db},]{csv/IGS2a_ac.csv}{\Freq}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\Freq}}\pgfmathparse{\val}\xdef\fb{\pgfmathresult}
```

Use linear interpolation to find the Y value between the 2 known points.